# Permission denied issue on uWSGI

Tags: django, virtualenv, uwsgi, virtualenvwrapper

I have setup a django-based project on an Ubuntu 13.04 Server.
I could run this project with 'root' priviledges on uWSGI configuration file.
But when I try to run this with standard 'www-data' user I got:

```
chdir(): Permission denied [uwsgi.c line 1851]
```

I have changed ownership of my project and its appropriate virtualenv folder to 'www-data' but get this error again!

My uWSGI config file is something like this:

```
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /root/my_project
# Django's wsgi file
module          = my_project.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /root/.virtualenvs/my_project

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = unix:///root/my_project/server.uwsgi.sock

chmod-socket    = 666
uid     = www-data
gid     = www-data


# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
```

What's the wrong?

Comment: is that directory `chown`'d by another user?

Comment: Nope! dear @AaronLelevier. 

All the folders mentioned in uWSGI file that I have brought is `chown`'ed by user `www-data` which membered in group `www-data`

Answer (score 2):

Your `chdir`, `home`, `socket` directives all use `/root/` as their base, which is `root` user'svhome directory and therefore other users don't have access there. Also there might be some SELinux limitations.

Try to create a separate folder for your project, i.e. in `/home/` (`/home/www-data`), make sure your `www-data` user has access to it and rights, and move your project and venv there, then change the settings (including `socket`) and try again.

Comment: Regarding to /root/ you're right, but I have given Permission to applied folders and their subcontents.

Comment: Starting from `/root` itself? Because if you have given permissions to `/root/my_project` and forgot `/root` itself it won't help. Also, as I said there's a nasty thing - SELinux contexts and etc., so my advice stays the same - move to less restricted folder, after that you might also want to try to disable SELinux to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved easily by adding a 0 (0www-data) before the user name.
If you don't care about safety, cause it grants root.